# AWS HTTP Api Route To lambda Integration shell(cli) command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-http-api

I want to automate things. I have created a AWS lambda using shell command. And also **HTTP** route using shell command in API Gateway. Now i want to connect the route and lambda using shell command. Can anyone explain the command how to achieve it.
**NOTE** Its http Api, not rest api

I have read the integration command it take ARN of lambda. But i might be missing "how to attach that with route".

Answer (score 0):

White creating a route using aws cli, we have a --target option, in this option need to point "integrations/integrationID"
While we create itegration we got the IntegrationID as out put.